# How do I rename multiple files using a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell

I am a beginner at shell scripting. I have 4 images:

```
 1.png, 2.png, 3.png, 4.png
```

How do I rename these images to:

```
img1.png, img2.png, img3.png, img4
```

Comment: Did you try searching `rename file bash` ? Clearly you didn't because the first result tells you how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Using perl based [rename](http://man.he.net/?section=all&topic=rename):

```
rename 's/^/img/' *.png
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this as a script with your file names as input. It is untested, but should give you a clue

```
#! /bin/bash    
for file in "$@"; do
     mv "$file" "img${file}"
done
```

Comment: You're welcome; on second thought, perhaps using `for file in *.png; do` is a  more direct way of demonstrating this otherwise nice `bash` solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look for the rename command, you can do something like

```
rename s/^/img/g *png
```

This substitutes (`s/`) the beginning of a file name (noted as the `^`) with `img` for all files ending in png (`*png`)

.if you don't have it, you can get the command from here http://stackoverflow.org/wiki/Rename.pl

for instance

Comment: The Perl-based `rename` utility is a good tip, but you should link to the more robust and more powerful version at http://plasmasturm.org/code/rename/. The `g` option is pointless here, because the `^` by definition can only match _once_ per line; also, you want `*.png` to avoid false positives.